# Alternative GUI for manager Display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Any time I change resolutions my desktop crashes, I've always found it difficult to manage multiple desktops. As seen in the screenshot. When I drag the displays around they just won't connect to each other. A reset is necessary at this point.

[image]

So is there an alternative GUI for handling this?

My error just if you're interested, but doesn't need answering is that I change, the screens flicker and then the images are throw all around the place so you are left with quarters of other screens in the opposite monitors.

Comment: But to make sure it is the GUI: if it is the GUI: start it from command line and watch for error notices. If those do not occur an alternative GUI will have the same problem.  I myself would assume it is the driver that is at fault. Are you using the prop or the open source version? And what happens when you change to the other driver? Probably doesn't matter but did you check the resolution are supported by each of the displays?

Comment: Interesting idea, I will play with drivers but I am using the prop drivers.